# Siddhi join events with data from DB

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I want to understand the "dos" and "dont dos" in siddhi. I saw DB connectors and possibilities to enrich stream events with data from DB (lets say the cassandra connector).

**Example**:

```
@primaryKey('id')
@store(type = 'rdbms', datasource = 'WSO2_TEST_DB')
define table BuyerInfoTable (id string, name string, address string, email string);

@info(name = 'EnrichBuyerInformation')
from ShipmentInfoStream as s join BuyerInfoTable as b
    on s.buyerId == b.id
select s.orderId, b.name, b.address, b.email, s.shipmentType
insert into ShipmentAndBuyerInfoStream;
```

Do I understand right, that this approach would mean that there is a select query made to the db on each incoming Event on the *ShipmentInfoStream* ?
In case yes - this sounds like a "dont do" for me - especially if we are talking about 100k events / sec.

Or am I understanding the architecture in a wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. As per the above query, when there is an event arrived in ShipmentInfoStream then there will be a DB query, get the output and process further.

But, this operation could be improved in various ways.

- If the DB table only contains limited values (and not changed by external users) then you could pre-load those events, keep in the in-memory event store and process them.
- You could use a cache to improve the performance. Check the "Caching In Memory" section in https://siddhi.io/en/next/docs/query-guide/#store ...